# How can I leverage MEF in my MVVM application?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

Can anybody give me a simple wpf application using mef and following mvvm pattern. I have looked a lot on the internet but i found very few examples and those example are very complex to understand. some examples are wpf, mef but dont follow mvvm pattern.

here is what i am trying to do.

There will a main wpf application. This will load all the modules (plugins) and show it to user. A module will contain 2 or 3 pages with next back buttons (used for navigation). Now when in main application i select a module, module opens or what you can say it replaces current window and on button navigation it changes views of the module.

> Main Window -> Module 1 -> Page 1
>
> ```
>                        Page 2
>
>                        Page 3
>
>            Module 2 -> Page 1
>
>                        Page 2
>
>                        Page 3
> ```

So it look clean now. Module 1 is a seperate project, module 2 is a seperate project. main window reads modules from dll and show them. clicking a module will go through its pages.

Comment: what kind of application you want to create with mef, wpf and mvvm? its better to ask a not so vage question.

Comment: @blindmeis i have updated the question, now u can see it. I hope it is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft has a few reference implementations lying around that you may find useful. they are a good showcase of MVVM / MEF and WPF. [here's](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gblock/archive/2008/06/12/stocktrader-ri-using-castle-windsor.aspx) the very first blog about the StockTrader RI implementation with the download link pointing [here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/SourceControl/DownloadSourceCode.aspx?changeSetId=12511). the Microsoft overview of the StockTrader RI and MVVM RI implementations are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405483%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx), and [here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921074%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) the StockTrader RI implementation specifically. hth.

Comment: `The sample application illustrates the use of ASP.NET and Windows Communication Foundation (WCF) technologies in an end-to-end service-oriented architecture running in the cloud. As such, the application illustrates many best-practice programming practices for the Windows Azure Platform, SQL Azure, ASP.NET and WCF including the use of an n-tier, service-oriented design.` wrong link?

Comment: is it really uses wpf, mvvm, mef. it is a cloud application i think. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I know the app you're talking about... I think it gets installed when you install PRISM. It's a great start for MEF. If you can find the link I'll give you a +1 :)

Comment: you're right, I mixed up the StockTrader app with the StockTrader RI app in my earlier answer. fixed it, hope that's better.

Comment: `The Page Could Not Be Found` - that's why castle answers are bad.  _[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)_

Answer (score 3):

i did 2 projects these days which do that what you want. what i have done is to set up a main project which does nothing more than collecting the modules via MEF and handle the selection of the module. you also need a component project where you set up the interfaces and export attributes.

here some sample code **pieces**:

MainProject app.xaml.cs

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    [ImportMany]
    private IEnumerable<Lazy<IComponent, IComponentMetadata>> _components;
    private CompositionContainer _mefcontainer;

    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

        //i do login stuff here

        //i use task.factory here and dynamic splashscreen here

        this.MefContainer.ComposeParts(rahmen, this);

        foreach (var component in _components)
        {
            //check metadata and fill modules collection
        }

        //add modules collection to mainwindowviewmodel

         ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose;

         this.MainWindow.Show();

    }
}
```

Component.dll

```
public interface IComponent//Marker interface
{
    bool HasChanges { get; }
}

public interface IComponentMetadata
{
    string Displayname { get; }

    int SortIndex { get; }

    string ImagePath { get; }

    string IconPath { get; }
}

[MetadataAttribute]
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ComponentExportAttribute : ExportAttribute, IComponentMetadata
{
    private const string DEFAULTICON = "pack://application:,,,/MyComponent;Component/Images/Default.png";


    public ComponentExportAttribute(string displayname, int sortindex): base(typeof(IComponent))
    {
        this.Displayname = displayname;
        this.SortIndex = sortindex;

        this.ImagePath = DEFAULTICON;
        this.IconPath = DEFAULTICON;
    }


    public ComponentExportAttribute(string displayname, int sortindex, string imagepath, string iconpath): base(typeof(IComponent))
    {
        this.Displayname = displayname;
        this.SortIndex = sortindex;

        this.ImagePath = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(imagepath) ? DEFAULTICON : imagepath;
        this.IconPath = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(iconpath) ? DEFAULTICON : iconpath;
    }

    #region Implementation of IComponentMetadata

    public string Displayname { get; private set; }

    public int SortIndex { get; private set; }

    public string ImagePath { get; private set; }

    public string IconPath { get; private set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Modul example

```
[ComponentExport("Test1",  150
    , "pack://application:,,,/TestProject;Component/Test/Logo1.png"
    , "pack://application:,,,/TestProject;Component/Test/Icon1.png")]
public partial class Test1MainWindow : UserControl, IComponent
{
    [ImportingConstructor]//if you want to do DI
    public Test1MainWindow ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
    }

    #region Implementation of IComponent

    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

or viewmodel export --> (if you do this you have to export a datatemplate to the mainapp, i can show this if you want)

```
[ComponentExport("Test2", 500 
    , "pack://application:,,,/TestProject;Component/Test/Logo2.png"
    , "pack://application:,,,/TestProject;Component/Test/Icon2.png")]
public class Test2: INPCBase, IComponent
{

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public Test2()
    {
    }

    #region Implementation of IKabuComponent

    public bool HasChanges
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: can you post the solution somewhere. like skydrive or mediafire.