# C# WPF Plugin Architecture

Tags: c#, wpf, plugins, architecture

What's the best way to implement a WPF plugin system in which each plugin handles its own window/s?
I understand the basics of the plugin architecture, and have an engine that loads external dlls (plugins), and each plugin implements my plugin interface. Each plugin handles its own logic, but I am not entirely sure how to go about having each plugin have its own window. Any thoughts or comments would help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/) can be a good tool for what you describe.

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377860/how-can-i-leverage-mef-in-my-mvvm-application) and [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43625/Building-an-Extensible-Application-with-MEF-WPF-an).