# MEF automaically resolve object

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mef

I need to use MEF and MVVM pattern for my WPF app.

Actually I have a ViewModel so definied:

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
class MainVM 
{        
    IServiceA serviceA;        
    IServiceB serviceB;

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainVM(IServiceA serviceA, IServiceB serviceB)
    {
        this.serviceA = serviceA;
        this.serviceB = serviceB;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(serviceA.Time);
    }
}
```

For the VM retrieving, I make use of a VMLocator, so made:

```
class ViewModelLocator
{
    static ViewModelLocator instance;

    public MainVM MainVM
    {
        get
        {
            MainVM output = MefBootstrap.Container.GetExportedValue<MainVM>();
            return output;
        }
    }

    protected ViewModelLocator()
    {

    }

    public static ViewModelLocator Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance ?? (instance = new ViewModelLocator());
        }
    }
}
```

called from XAML:

```
DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static provider:ViewModelLocator.Instance}, Path=MainVM}"
```

This code actually works.

What I wonder if realizable is to automatically Import VM using only MEF ExportAttribute *[Import]* on the attribute declaration of VMLocator instead of using *GetExportValue()* method.

Is the any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried it? What was the problem when you did?

Comment: MainVM is not resolved at all. I tried with 
[Import] public MainVM MainVM { get; set; }

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you manually create `ViewModelLocator`. Since you create it manually **IoC(MEF)** does not have control over this instance creation and thus it will not `[Import]` dependency(`MainVM`) from container into your `property`.

So to address the question "Is there any solution?":

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378748/5505949) is an example of how to leverage MEF in MVVM context.

I strongly advice you go with [PRISM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx). It already has it done for you. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel especially this one.

Comment: I take a look at PRISM + MEF solution, honestly I prefer to keep up my way, because there is too much logic involved on bootstrapping

Comment: Well for MEF solution you actually need a higher "glue" class which would create new usercontrol and new viewmodel and then glue them together.

Comment: I ended up using this old but good solution, which is also compatible with MEF.
https://wpftutorial.net/ReferenceArchitecture.html

The only bad thing is that suppose a bit of code behind, but is also untied from container.

Hovever it's still unclear to me how to call others view, because these are not called from App.xml module